# How to change what your website says when linked?

Tags: html

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm pretty new. How can I change what it says when my website gets linked? For example, if someone on discord sends a link to something like twitter, it will say their name, how many tweets they've sent, and show their pfp. How could I change it to something like that for my website? I want to put an image and description when someone links my site.

Comment: [Check this article](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/)

Comment: Thanks, that helps! For some reason, I can't mark your response as the answer, I can only flag it as a problem.